# Access rights of a lambda capturing this

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    void public_test()
    {
        [this]() { private_test(); }();
    }

private:
    void private_test()
    {
        std::cout << "test\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    test().public_test();
}
```

The lambda captures this and then calls a private method of the captured object. Now this code compiles and works (prints `test`) using VC++ 2012. Whereas this is quite intuitive and useful behaviour, I'd like to know if this is guaranteed to work by standard. Thus, does a lambda have private access to any object captured through `this`?

I tried to look this up in the standard reading through *5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]* but could not really find a definite answer (being not that well-versed in the depths of the standard). The only paragraph that seemed useful to me is

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the
>   closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type — called the
>   closure type — whose properties are described below. This class type
>   is not an aggregate (8.5.1). The closure type is declared in the
>   smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains
>   the corresponding lambda-expression. [ Note: This determines the set
>   of namespaces and classes associated with the closure type (3.4.2).
>   The parameter types of a lambda-declarator do not affect these
>   associated namespaces and classes. —end note ]

But on the other a normal local class type defined in a member function doesn't have private access to the surrounding class. So a lambda having private access would somehow raise lambdas above mere syntactic sugar for a local function object to something more involved, since it would need additional "compiler magic" to somehow make it a friend of the surrounding class.

So does a lambda have private access to any object captured through `this` and if yes, which parts of the standard allow this happen?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think the fact that it is a lambda is relevant.  All lambda does
is define a local class.  And according to §11/2: "A local class of a
member function may access the same names that the member function
itself may access."

Comment: *"A local class of a member function may access the same names that the member function itself may access."* - Ah, so that was the part where I was wrong. It seems I need to refresh my knowledge about acces rights of local and member types. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau That's something that was changed (or at least clarified) in C++11.  (I think it corresponds to the original intent, but IIRC, C++03, or at least C++98, didn't make it clear, and may even have said something contrary.)

Comment: This simply isn't true.  I wrapped a method implementation in a lamda and all of the sudden it could no longer call a private method that the original method could call.  So it seems more like 'A local class of a member function may access the same names that the member function itself may access.... EXCEPT private method names'.