# Private constructor and make_shared

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a singleton class with a private constructor. In the static factory method I do the following:

```
shared_ptr<MyClass> MyClass::GetInstance()
{
    static once_flag onceFlag;

    call_once(onceFlag, []() {
        if (_instance == nullptr)
            _instance.reset(new MyClass());
    });

    return _instance;
}
```

If I use

```
_instance = make_shared<MyClass>();
```

the code does not compile. My question is: why `new` can invoke a private constructor but `make_shared` not?

Comment: This code makes no sense because sharing ownership of singleton is pointless when you still keep an instance of `shared_ptr` for yourself (I assume that `_instance` is `shared_ptr< MyClass >`) and checking whether `_instance` is nullptr is pointless because this block is protected by once flag. And making `make_shared` work (by declaring it a friend for example) in this case makes no sense as well because then it would be possible to create instances of `MyClass` everywhere.

Comment: OK, I get your point, the condition ``if (_instance == nullptr)`` is not necessary. _instance is a static class variable. What i do not understand is why a ``shared_ptr`` does not make sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call ::std::make\_shared on a class with only protected or private constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As mentioned, `std::make_shared` or its component parts don't have access to private members.
2. the `call_once` and `once_flag` are un-necessary. They are implicit in c++11 static initialisation,
3. You normally would not want to expose the shared pointer.

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass() {}

public:
    static MyClass& GetInstance()
    {
        static auto instance = MyClass();
        return instance;
    }
};
```

However, there is one case I can imagine where you would want to expose a shared pointer to the impl - this is in the case where the class can choose to 'break off' or 'reset' the impl to a new one. In this case I would consider code like this:

```
class MyClass2
{
    MyClass2() {};

    static auto& InternalGetInstance()
    {
        static std::shared_ptr<MyClass2> instance { new MyClass2 };
        return instance;
    }

public:

    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass2> GetInstance()
    {
        return std::atomic_load(std::addressof(InternalGetInstance()));
    }

    static void reset() {
        std::atomic_store(std::addressof(InternalGetInstance()),
                        std::shared_ptr<MyClass2>(new MyClass2));

    }  
};
```

However, in the end, it is my view that 'staticness' of a class should be an implementation detail, and unimportant to the user of the class:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class MyClass
{
    // internal mechanics

    struct Impl {

        auto doSomething() {
            // actual implementation here.
        }
    };

    // getImpl now becomes the customisation point if you wish to change the
    // bahviour of the class later
    static Impl& getImpl() {
        static auto impl = Impl();
        return impl;
    }


    // use value semantics - it makes for more readable and loosely-coupled code
public:
    MyClass() {}

    // public methods defer to internal implementation

    auto doSomething() {
        return getImpl().doSomething();
    }
};


int main() {

    // note: just create objects
    auto mc = MyClass();
    mc.doSomething();

    // now we can pass the singleton as an object. Other functions don't even
    // need to know it's a singlton:

    extern void somethingElse(MyClass mc);
    somethingElse(mc);
}

void somethingElse(MyClass mc)
{

}
```

Comment: If I abstract from things that do not address the actual question, what remains is that the mechanism invoked by `make_shared` does not retain the privilege of accessing private members (here the default constructor) that the caller of `make_shared` had; by contrast the constructor call in `new myClass()` is done in the context of the caller itself (here the lambda inside `myClass::getInstance`), not inside the implementation of `new`, so the privilege is retained in that case. In other words `make_shared` forwarding  is not perfect: it retains rvalue/lvalue distinction, but not privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Please take [VTT's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127107/private-constructor-and-make-shared/45127266#comment77224240_45127107) seriously.

---

To your question:

> My question is: why new can invoke a private constructor but make_shared not?

The `new` is actually used within a lambda in a *member-function*; Well, A lambda defines a *local-class*, and C++ standards [permits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731290/1621391) a *local-class* within a *member-function* to access everything the *member-function* can access. And its trivial to remember that member functions can access privates..

`std::make_shared` has no access to the *privates* of `MyClass`. It's outside the scope of `MyClass`

---

Example:

```
class X{
    X(){};
public:
    static X* create(){ // This member-function can access private functions and ctors/dtor
        auto lm = [](){ // This lambda inherits the same access of enclosing member-function
               return new X();
        };
        return lm();
    }
};

int main(){
    auto x = X::create();    //valid;
    auto y = new X();        //invalid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Meyers singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-the-singleton-pattern-thread-safe) instead. You should ensure that your compiler supports C++11 magic static before.