# How to provide a callable object protected access like lambda in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I have a lambda that I need to convert into a callable object so that I can specialize the call operator. My impression has always been that a lambda with an `void(auto)` signature was equivalent to a callable struct roughly like this:

```
struct callable {
    Foo & capture;

    template< typename T >
    void operator()( T arg ) { /* ... */ }
}
```

However, a lambda can access private and protected members when it is declared within a member function.

Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
protected:
    void a() { cout << "YES" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void call1();
    void call2();
};


struct callable {
    B * mB;

    void operator()() {
        // This does not compile: 'void A::a()' is protected within this context
        // mB->a();
    }
};

void B::call1() {
    // but then how does this access a() ?!
    [&]() { a(); }();
}

void B::call2() {
    callable c{ this };
    c();
}


int main()
{
    B b;

    b.call1();
    b.call2();
}
```

Is there any way to emulate that behavior in a callable struct, without declaring it in the header and making it a friend class? That seems problematic because I'm going to have a lot of different callables. I'm also just curious about it, because I was under the impression that lambdas were functionally identical to declaring a struct with a call operator.

[Access rights of a lambda capturing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731215/access-rights-of-a-lambda-capturing-this) seems to say that the lambda has the same access as a local class. But in my case, I need to emulate a generic lambda, and local classes can't have template member functions.

Comment: "so that I can specialize the call operator" -- sounds like a bad plan really.  Why, and are you willing to reconsider?  Overloading is much more cromulant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still capture `this` and `&B::a`

```
struct callable {
    B* mB;
    void (A::*m)();

    void operator()() const {
        (mB->*m)();
    }
};

void B::call2() {
    callable c{ this, &B::a };
    c();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acd2d4e3242758e6)

Comment: Clever! But--to my surprise--that errors on compile with `'void A::a()' is protected within this context` when instantiating callable. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bc612b89ab1dc5e

Comment: You have to use `&B::a` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `struct callable` a `friend` of `B` without providing a definition for it.  Such a declaration doesn't even make the name visible until the real declaration is encountered:

```
class B : public A {
  // ...
  friend struct callable;
}

// ERROR: callable isn't visible here:
// callable *foo;
```

This can be extended to hack in a large number of friends with one declaration if brevity is really important:

```
class B : public A {
  // ...
  template<int> friend struct callable;
};

// In implementation:
template<>
struct callable<0> { /* ... */ };
template<>
struct callable<1> { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: OP states *"without declaring it in the header and making it a friend class?"*.

Comment: You don't have to give the full definition of `callable` in the header.  It isn't clear to me whether the OP considers a forward declaration to be "declaring it in the header".

Comment: Yeah, declaring a parent class a friend and inheriting from that one class might be an ok solution, if friend status was inherited. Unfortunately it's not.

Comment: You can succinctly create many friends with the template hack I added.  (This avoids having to have the one friend provide a forwarding function for each member of `A` that you want to use.)